# jQuery orientationchange DOM not ready (iPhone 5)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, orientation-changes, event-listener

When an orientation change fires I need to recalculate width of a specific element based on the width of other responsive elements of the page.

The problem is that the DOM is not ready when the callback of the `orientationchange` listener is fired:

```
$(window).on("orientationchange", function() {
    var newWidth = $("#elem1").width() - $("#elem2").width();
    $("#elemToResize").width(newWidth);
});
```

The computed width of elem1 and elem2 are the old ones (in the previous device orientation), thus the newWidth value is wrong. Is there any clean solution here that avoid to use a timeOut?

ps: I am experiencing this issue on an iPhone 5s

Comment: Don't update the UI based on the width of the client using JS. Use CSS media queries. This is *exactly* what they are for, and they perform much, much better. I know that you're calculating a value, but it should be possible to achieve the same logic if you structure the rules correctly; using % values for example

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks I've solved using calc function of css, much cleaner solution.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted